# Aggregating lambda expressions with a statement bodies

Tags: c#

I'm bulding a dynamic expression which includes reflection:

```
Expression<Func<Order, bool>> acc = null;

foreach(var accessRight in user.AccessRights)
{
   Expression<Func<Order, bool>> curr = o => 
        (string)o.GetType().GetProperty(accessRight.Type).GetValue(o) == accessRight.Value;

   acc = acc == null ? curr : acc.OrElse(curr);
}
```

It works, but doesn't feel very safe in terms of null checks. I would like to enhance it to something like this:

```
Expression<Func<Order, bool>> curr = o => 
{
    var pi = o.GetType().GetProperty(accessRight.Type);
    if(pi != null)
    {
        var propertyValue = pi.GetValue(o);
        return propertyValue == accessRight.Value;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since I cannot convert a lambda expression with a statement body to an expression tree, I'm not sure how to proceed. I've looked in to related SO threads, but can't say that they helped me here. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using C# 6 you could use the null conditional operator `o => 
        (string)o.GetType().GetProperty(accessRight.Type)?.GetValue(o) == accessRight.Value;` unless `GetValue` and `accessRight.Value` can both be `null`.

Comment: Even before C# 6 you can use `o.GetType().GetProperty() != null ? o.GetType().GetProperty().GetValue(...) : false`

Comment: @juharr No, it may not contain a null propagating operator

Comment: @Evk Yeah, I was hoping there was a prettier option :)

Comment: That works? Putting a *lambda* as the operand to an or-else is a strange thing to do. Normally you'd put the *body* of the lambda as the operand.

Comment: @EricLippert I pretty much based it on this blog post: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dbmGOLCgChoJ:https://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2008/08/02/query-objects-with-repository-pattern-part-2/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=se . If you search for "void addCriteria" you can find the relevant part. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @EricLippert That's not the .NET `OrElse` method (it's not an instance method on `Expression<T>`), meaning it's a custom extension method that presumably rips out the bodies of the two lambdas and combines them.

Comment: @Servy Correct. I just linked to the relevant code. My bad

Comment: @Servy: Hence my confusion. Thanks for clarifying!